# Тире или двоеточие нужно поставить в заголовке?

Tags: пунктуация, заголовок, тире-или-двоеточие

**Вниманию туристов () можно ли при поездке в Бангладеш обойтись без визы?**

После слова "туристов" должно стоять двоеточие или тире? И по какому правилу?

Comment: Туристам предлагается ответить на вопрос?  Варианты ответа даются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вниманию туристов: можно ли при поездке в Бангладеш обойтись без визы**

**Пояснение**

Двоеточие ставится, так как вторая часть заголовка раскрывает  содержание первой части: вниманию туристов (предлагается следующая информация).

Вопросительный знак в этих случаях обычно не используется, так как это ответ на  вопрос.

**Пример:**

Travel.ru. Новости туризма. **Вниманию туристов: в Кению нельзя ввозить полиэтиленовые пакеты**